# Strong one way hash for weak passwords

Tags: hash, cryptography, aes, bcrypt, scrypt

I searching for a strong one way hashing function which encrypts (really) weak passwords (10^9 combinations). The crypt function also must fulfill some requirements:

1. Alwas same hash from same clear text. So scrypt/bcrypt and public/private key methods are not possible (or may I be wrong here?).
2. No shared secret as in AES. As the same hashes have to be created by different clients.
3. No salts

So what could be done to increase the difficulty of bruteforcing against a such small character space? I already tried key stretching with multiple rounds of SHA256 but i am not how many rounds are required to significally increase computation time (Must be in the billions I guess).
The only thing i came up with so far is using a server side secret which gets added to the password. But in case of corruption it is difficult to guarantee that the secret is still a secret...
I would be glad for some hints or ideas!
regards,
r0cks

Comment: You might get a better advice on http://security.stackexchange.com or http://crypto.stackexchange.com/ but as for me, you can't get extra entropy out of nowhere, other than running PBKDF or BCrypt for dozens of thousands of rounds.

Comment: What is the reason, that the same clear text must result in the same hash value? Do you want to compare them? Even without this restriction, it is nearly impossible to protect weak passwords, you can only make it a bit more difficult. Could you explain a bit more about your intentions?

Comment: I want to identify datasets with the mentioned hashes as keys. And to keep privacy those hashes should be (quite) secure. In the end the connections between datasets should not be kept server side but client side.

Comment: What are those keys, are they ids of database rows, or keywords to search for? What do you mean with privacy, do you want to prevent the keys from displaying in the browser, should they be hidden in the internet connection, or do you want to hide them in your database on the server?

Comment: The context shouldn't matter in this case but I guess in the end it comes to a server side secret.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible using just an algorithm. You are better off splitting off your system into parts with specific roles to protect your data.

scrypt, bcrypt and PBKDF2 are all deterministic Password Based Key Derivation Functions (PBKDFs). As long as the salt stays the same, they will reproduce the same result for the same input. (Parts of) the salt may be a server side secret. If the salt gets exposed those functions will however not help much if the password is weak.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and i think you are right. In the end i have to use something server side to increase entropy...

Answer (score 1):

It is not easy to give a good answer without more context.

A server side secret can only protect the ids(?) for storing them server side (database). Even then it only protects the ids as long as the secret is not known (the problem of every two-way encryption).

A one-way hash on the other side would protect the ids even when the code and the database was stolen. A BCrypt/PBKDF2 hash would slow down brute-forcing, even with a static salt, though the static salt would allow to build a single rainbow-table to get all hashes at once.

Using BCrypt and afterwards encrypt the hash with a server side secret is possibly your best bet, though it is difficult to say without knowing more of the scenario.

Comment: Thanks for your answer this helps. I would like to upvote your answer but I can't.

Comment: No problem, just ask when the answer is not clear and you can deliver more information about the scenario.