# How can we ensure the uniqueness of encrypted phonenumber data?

Tags: database, encryption, aes, social-networking, sha

#### Situation:

We collect user phone numbers and encrypt them using AES256 in GCM mode before storing them in a database. This method produces different encryption values for the same phone number input. How can we ensure the uniqueness of the input phone numbers?

#### Questions

1. Is there another method to ensure the uniqueness of encrypted phone numbers apart from the approach I've tried?
2. The issue I want to address involves receiving a contact list from users, comparing phone numbers, and returning user information if it matches a user in the app, similar to Instagram or Facebook. However, if there are 1000 numbers in the contact list, implementing my attempted method (as described above) would require encrypting or decrypting 1000 times (even if AES was altered to always produce a consistent value), which I believe to be highly inefficient. Could you provide any solutions or hints on how this problem could be approached differently?

#### Attempted solution:

We introduced an additional column (hash_phone) set as unique and applied SHA256 to the input phone numbers to assess uniqueness.

Comment: It's a feature that encryption doesn't produce the same ciphertext for the same plaintext: that interferes with traffic analysis and replay attacks (see also ECB).  Of course, you don't really want such encryption: that would require that you decrypt every number to check it against each new one.  Your problem is then reduced to [hashing very weak passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23065439/strong-one-way-hash-for-weak-passwords); note that geographic information might easily lead an attacker to needing only 1000 times the effort you do, which is likely intractable.

Comment: @DavisHerring: That dupe looks wrong to me. Also, just out of curiosity, how did you manage to close the question with just your single vote?

Comment: There are some important missing details in your question, like key management. Where do your AES keys come from? Also, AES is reasonably fast, why do you think otherwise?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk: Community closed it, which I think means the asker agreed.